# parsing BEP9(ut_metadata) data message

Tags: bittorrent

BEP9(ut_metadata) data message has a `total_size` field and I'm having trouble seeing what it means.

The message is in this format:

```
<4-byte length prefix><20><1-byte extended msg id><bencode part><piece data>
```

I'm confused about two things:

1. Does length-prefix include `<piece data>` part?
2. What does `total_size` field in `bencode_part` specify?

It looks to me like we don't need `total_size`, unless I'm misunderstanding something.

Here is currently how I'm parsing it:

- Length prefix includes `<piece data>` so I know exactly how big this message is. I'm reading that many bytes.
- After parsing `<bencode_part>`, I'm just consuming rest of the bytes and consider this the data.

Can anyone help me understanding this format?

Thanks.

Comment: I think the message format you describe is lacking the extension header nested within the standard bittorrent header.

Comment: You're right, Just edited the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. yes
2. the total length of the info section of the .torrent file. The metadata may be transferred in multiple chunks if they are too big for a single message.

Comment: But isn't length of the info sections already sent in handshake? Why send it again and again in every data message?

Comment: Because the spec says so. "This key has the same semantics as the "metadata_size" in the extension header"

Comment: I've got a question. If you only have the `info hash` and nothing else, how do you then get the metadata from the peers?

Comment: @jakewong you use the DHT to find peers and then the extended handshake and the metadata extension to get it.

Comment: @the8472 Okay, I manage to get the extended handshake and metadata from the peers. I'm however, still stuck in B-decoding the metadata. But i'll post another question about it instead of on this thread. Thank you!